# What is a word to describe a person that is too kind (in a negative way)?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe a person that is:

- always trying to treat others nicely, kindly,
- afraid of saying or doing something that makes others upset,
- never say or think about what he/she really wants, only try to make everyone happy.

This word is usually talking about a child or woman that has suffered from something terrible that made them become this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjective to describe people being over cautious to be polite or considerate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341885/adjective-to-describe-people-being-over-cautious-to-be-polite-or-considerate) ('obsequious')

Answer (score 0):

A ***pushover***

> someone who is easy to influence or persuade, or an opponent who is easy to defeat
> Colonel Moore was a kind and sympathetic man, but no pushover. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pushover))